# Проверить существование функции

Tags: jquery

В `jq` есть способ проверить, существует ли такая функция или нет?

Comment: о какой именно функции идет речь? функции вообще? методе jQuery?

Comment: Есть написанная функция в отдельном файле. Файл не подключен ко всем станицам. Вот и хочу проверять, существует та функция или нет.

Comment: нужно знать как объявлена функция в этом файле

Comment: Это getObjectIdEx

Comment: это не объявление.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция объявлена, если `typeof название_функции == 'function'`

```js
function moo() { /***/ }

if (typeof moo == 'function') {
  console.log('moo exists');
}

if (typeof foo == 'function') {
  console.log('foo exists');
}
```

Comment: тут еще надо учитывать когда делается проверка и как объявлена функция в другом файле (может она вообще внутри IIFE и потом куда-то заносится) ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯